# loading sounds with viewpager ONLOAD on android

Tags: android, audio, android-viewpager

So basically, I want to have a starting sound effects as the first view is loaded in my viewpager. I am able to get the sound for the other pages using setOnPageChangeListener.

So again I ask, how do I put the sound in my viewpager as it is loaded?

my current viewpager codes goes like this

```
mAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            mSoundManager.playSound(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

        }
    });
```

EDIT: Solved

I have found a solution, I don't know if it's currently the best or the right solution but here's what I did.

I used SoundPool as my sound effects, so I simply used

```
mSoundManager.mSoundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener(){
        @Override
        public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {

            if(!firstSound){
                mSoundManager.playSound(1);
                System.out.println("FLASHCARD onLoadSound");
                firstSound=true;
            }
        }
    });
```

the reason why I have a Boolean firstSound is that the sound produced is launched three times, so what I did was, if the sound is made, I flag the firstSound to be true.

Comment: there is no method by the viewpager that has the onLoad() like function.. can anyone help me please? :D